# I tried to add color to half of image (50% size of image) but I couldn't give value in flutter

Tags: flutter, colorfilter

I tried to add color using ColorFiltered widget to half of image (50% size of image) but I couldn't give value in flutter when I give value then show me error.How I give size or value?

code

```
ColorFiltered(
                colorFilter: const ColorFilter.matrix([
                  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, //
                  2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, //
                  0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, //
                  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, //
                ]),
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/bar.png",
                ),
              ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCNJr.png)

Answer (score 1):

What if you used a `Stack` and position a `Container` with the background Color you want, behind your image. Then You could just move the `Container` to the right or left, giving the illusion of loading. (Assuming your image is transparent.)

I think this should be easier and much more convenient than using a matrix.